Impressions – a cryptic crossword

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. Past prog rockers (RIP) drinking whisky (10)
6. Acting award for Mr Hopkins, according to inside source? (4)
9. Clean up after last bit of tofu remaining on plate, perhaps (7)
10. Mystical life force is miles out in a novel (7)
12. With, ultimately, colour like famed, musical Mr Sheeran? (3-6)
14. Server giving it up for female host in Communion? (5)
15. Kentucky's foremost prog rockers describing component of underwater forest? (4)
17. Ethiopian people harassed pair within confines of Slovak wildlife viewing area (6,4)
19. Paid £1 to go aboard Delta that's running behind schedule? (10)
20. Setter imitates Liberal cultural icon (4)
22. Unopened arcade machine missing essential element in turbine altogether (2,3)
23. Dictator in British vehicle confiscating American currency (9)
25. One offering donation perhaps welcomes Republican conman (7)
26. Slightly damaging front of gate? Devastating! (7)
27. Young fellows misled by Troy, Ken and others, say (4)
28. In hell, a great disorder (3,3,4)
Down
1. Murder during tag? So far I'm very impressed! (3,3,7,2)
2. Upper limits of double album size shortly going up (5)
3. "They get no lines of text", Rasputin assumed (6)
4. Heading for Limoges, having been evicted from French city a little further away (3)
5. Amazing emeralds smuggled in unopened containers for salesmen such as 6 across Stark (4,7)
7. Not controllable without much thought (3,2,4)
8. Unexpected email: "Unlike with orgy, so far I'm not impressed!" (3,3,7,2)
11. North Hollywood film studio hosts exciting premiere that's displaying someone with little previous experience (6)
13. Commander, raise alarm! I'd blundered! (4,7)
16. Talking in high quantity and high quality, with hints of Obama and Churchill (9)
18. Woman is physically aggressive, taking off top in nightclub (6)
21. Dry part of Cali in magic underground space (not OC) (6)
24. Current business area somewhere in the Mediterranean (5)
26. Crush spirit of corporation (3)

COMPLETED GRID

 

ACROSS

 1. YESTERYEAR = YES + TEAR drinking RYE
 6. TONY (ddef.)
 9. UNEATEN = NEATEN after _U
 10. MANITOU = M + (OUT IN A)*
 12. RED-HAIRED (&lit) = _R _E _D + HAIR + ED
 14. WAFER = WA(-it)ER giving up IT for F
 15. KELP = K_ + ELP
 17. SAFARI PARK = (AFAR + PAIR*) in S_K
 19. LIQUIDATED = I QUID [£1] to go aboard (LATE + D [NATO Delta])
 20. IDOL = I [setter] + DO [as in do. for ditto...imitates] + L
 22. IN ALL = (-p, unopened)IN(-b, missing essential element of turbine)ALL
 25. GRIFTER = GIFTER welcomes P
 26. GRAZING = G_ + RAZING
 27. TOYS [Ken and others, say] = (-b)OYS [young fellows misled] by T [abbreviation for Troy, as in Troy ounce] (h/t juicifer...thanks!)
 28. ALL THE RAGE = (HELL A GREAT)* [awesome clue!]

DOWN

 1. YOU ARE KILLING IT = KILLING in YOU ARE IT
 2. SPEED = (D_E + EPS)<
 3. EXTRAS = _EXT RAS_
 4. YON = (-l)YON [L_ evicted]
 5. ARMS DEALERS = EMERALDS* in (-j)ARS
 7. OUT OF HAND (ddef.)
 8. YOU ARE KILLING ME = (EMAIL UNLIKE ORGY)*
 11. NEWBIE = (N [north] + WB) hosts E_ + IE [that's]
 13. REAR ADMIRAL = REAR [raise] + (ALARM I'D)*
 16. LOQUACITY = QUALITY* + O + C
 18. VIOLET = VIOLE(-n)T
 21. MOJAVE = MOJ(-o) + (-c)AVE
 23. MUSSOLINI = MINI confiscating US + SOL
 24. IBIZA = I [symbol for amperage in electronics] + BIZ + A [area]
 26. GUT (tdef!) (h/t juicifer...thanks!)


I think 27a is actually {OBLF jvgu gur svefg yrggre (zvfyrq) punatrq gb G (Gebl)} and 26 d is {n gevcyr qrs (pehfu = qrfgebl = thg, fcvevg = pbhentr = thg, pbecbengvba = oryyl = thg)}
